# Windows Phone 8.1 RT - Popup which show up in entire application

Tags: windows-runtime, popup, windows-phone-8.1

I'm want to make a popup screen which is handle by application and can show up in entire application. I mean that I need to make popup that can show up in many pages depending on when specific requirement is executed.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a [link](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Windows-Phone-81-samples-08631ca7) for windows phone 8.1 samples when you download it, open one of Xaml sample projects in there they have a textblock in the mainpage.xaml which is used for status message and they call it from each page when something is executed. You can follow there way and make it for your specific needs.